# Linked List in C and getifaddrs()

Tags: c++, c, linux, linked-list

I've a problem with linked list. I'm using getifaddrs() to get ifaces info in Linux.

At first, i created an struct for save the interfaces infos.

This is a struct:

```
  typedef struct iface {
    char * interface_name;
    char * interface_addr_ipv4;
    char * interface_addr_ipv6;
    char * interface_netmask;
    char * interface_broadcast;
    char * interface_mac_addr;
    int interface_active;
    struct iface * next_interface;

    } Interface;
```

After this, i identify all ifaces of system in this way, even if they are not configured with an IP:

```
    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1)
        return GET_INFO_IFACES_FAILED;
    struct iface * iface_aux;
    struct ifaddrs * ifaddr_aux;
    struct sockaddr_in * ip;

    iface_aux = iface;
    for (ifaddr_aux=ifaddr;ifaddr_aux!=NULL;ifaddr_aux=ifaddr_aux->ifa_next) {
        iface_aux->interface_name = ifaddr_aux->ifa_name;

        if (ip->sin_family == AF_PACKET) {
            get_interface_mac_addr(iface_aux);
            iface_aux->interface_addr_ipv4 = NULL;
            iface_aux->interface_addr_ipv6 = NULL;
            iface_aux->next_interface = (Interface *) malloc(sizeof (Interface));
            iface_aux = iface_aux->next_interface;
            iface_aux->next_interface = NULL;
        }
    }
```

After all this, i do other loop to get ip address of interfaces, this is the code:

```
iface_aux = iface; //go to the firts pointer
for (ifaddr_aux=ifaddr;ifaddr_aux!=NULL;ifaddr_aux=ifaddr_aux->ifa_next) {
    ip = (struct sockaddr_in *) ifaddr_aux->ifa_addr;
    if (ip->sin_family == AF_INET) {
        get_interface_ifaddr(iface_aux, ip);
        get_interface_netmask(iface_aux, ifaddr);
        get_interface_broadcast(iface_aux, ifaddr);
        iface_aux = iface_aux->next_interface;
    }
}
```

The code of function get_interface_ifaddr is:

```
int get_interface_ifaddr(Interface * iface, struct sockaddr_in * ip) {
    iface->interface_addr_ipv4 = inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr);
    if (iface->interface_addr_ipv4 == NULL)
       return GET_IFADDR_FAILED;
    return GET_IPADDR_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is, when i do another loop to see the interfaces infos, all nodes of the list, stay with the last ip:

```
for (iface_aux=iface;iface_aux->next_interface!=NULL;iface_aux=iface_aux->next_interface) {
    printf("Interface Name: %s\n", iface_aux->interface_name);
    printf("Interface IP: %s\n", iface_aux->interface_addr_ipv4);
}
```

The strange thing is that the name of the interfaces is correct, but when i get the address, all nodes of the list, are to the same address.

Someone know what is going on?

PS: i'm new in c and linked list.

Thanks for your atention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` uses a same memory region to return result. You need to allocate `interface_addr_ipv4` by yourself and to copy the data manually.

```
char *tmp = inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr);
iface->interface_addr_ipv4 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tmp) + 1)); /* Don't forget to free() */
strcpy(iface->interface_addr_ipv4, tmp);
```

From the [docs](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html):

> inet_ntoa() returns the dots-and-numbers string in a static buffer that is overwritten with each call to the function.

Better way is just to use `inet_ntop`:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, ip->sin_addr,
          iface->interface_addr_ipv4, sizeof(iface->interface_addr_ipv4));
```

Where `iface->interface_addr_ipv4` is an char array:

```
char interface_addr_ipv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
```

Comment: Which is why the OP (and anyone else) should stop using `inet_ntoa` and start using [`inet_ntop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) instead.

Comment: So, i allocate other space in memory for interface_addr_ipv4, using the malloc? Like this.
iface->interface_addr_ipv4 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) + 20);
iface->interface_addr_ipv4 = inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr);

Comment: Yes, or just make it an array and use `inet_ntop` (no need for `strncpy` then).

Comment: I just don't understand who i need free(). Who is?

Comment: If you allocate your memory with `malloc` you need to free it with `free(iface->interface_addr_ipv4)` when you no longer need it, to avoid memory leaking. Note that you can just skip `malloc` and allocate memory as `char interface_addr_ipv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];`. In this case you don't need `free`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37787/discussion-between-vitor-luis-and-nemanja-boric)

Comment: But. when i free iface->interface_addr_ipv4, in the moment to print the address, the printf prints nothing.

Comment: What approach are you using? inet_ntop or inet_ntoa? Did you allocated memory? Did you call strcpy?

Comment: I'm using inet_ntoa, i'm allocate memory and use strcpy. :D